# PHP calculate trend line like excel TREND function

Tags: php, excel, trendline

My math is very week and now still figuring how to achieve this with PHP.
I was using excel TREND() function.
Let's say I have 2 lists of known values

`| known_x_values | known_y_values |
|----------------|----------------|
| 323            | 0.038          |
| 373            | 0.046          |
| 423            | 0.053          |
| 473            | 0.062          |
| 523            | 0.071          |
| 573            | 0.080          |`

And now I need to know the value **y** when the **x = 428**.
By using excel TREND() function, I get **0.055** as the value y.

Anyone can show me how PHP handle this kind of math questions? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [TREND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TREND-function-e2f135f0-8827-4096-9873-9a7cf7b51ef1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) -> [LINEST function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) - The LINEST function calculates the statistics for a line by using the "least squares" method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel's `TREND()` uses the [least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Math is hard, so I'd use a library to do the heavy lifting. In this case [php-ai/php-ml](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml).

#### Example:

```
use Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares;

$x = [[323], [373], [423], [473], [523], [573]];
$y = [.038, .046, .053, .062, .071, .080];

$regression = new LeastSquares();
$regression->train($x, $y);
echo $regression->predict([428]);
```

#### Outputs:

```
0.054973333333333235
```

*Output may vary slightly depending on your precision setting.*

---

You can of course [`round()`](http://php.net/round) or [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) that result as you wish, e.g.:

```
echo number_format($regression->predict([428]), 3);
```

gives:

```
0.055
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul! your answer is very helpful!